# C++ How to enumerate QGraphicsItem's?

Tags: c++, qt

Using this function, I can delete selected `QGraphicsItem`'s from a `QGraphicsView`. 
How can I get my ellipses enumerated in order to receive a notification like `"Deleted ellipse n°..."`.

```
void MainWindow::deleteItem()
{
        foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, scene->selectedItems()) {
            if (item->type() == ellipse->Type) {
                scene->removeItem(item);
                delete item;
                QMessageBox::information(this,"Notification", "Deleted");
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways

Assuming you only care about that iteration:

```
   int ix = 0; // add this
   foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, scene->selectedItems()) {
        if (item->type() == ellipse->Type) {
            scene->removeItem(item);
            delete item;
            std::cout << "Deleted ellipse number " << ix++ << std::endl; // and add this
            QMessageBox::information(this,"Notification", "Deleted");
        }
    }
```

The above only works if your ordering only corresponds to that foreach() loop.  If your items are in some arbitrary order:

```
std::unordered_map<QGraphicsItem*, int> mGraphicsItems;
```

That's assuming you can populate it, of course.  If you can, do a lookup before calling delete(), to get the value which is the enumeration.  Not very elegant though, and adds space.

Other way is to subclass QGraphicsItem [Untested code but you get the idea]

```
class MyGraphicsItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     // snip
    int index() const { return mIndex; }
    void setIndex( int i ) { mIndex = i; }
private:
    int mIndex;
};
```

Just set the index in whatever way you want when the QGraphicsItem is created, and before calling delete, print out (or do whatever) with item->index();

Comment: The last way seems more elegant! So I was right, QGraphicItem's are not indexed by default (when created).

Comment: AFAIK, nothing in Qt is unless you want to count through each iteration of the container they are put in.  It gets really tricky you wan to catch signals by those objects and need to know which one it was.

Comment: @KiraSan if you want index every created object, you should use static counter variable. For example increment it in constructor and decrement in destructor(or not)